# How to using checkform function for next button?

Tags: javascript, validation

I want to use function checkform for next button onnly.

If user click BACK Button , not checkfrom, How can i do ?

..................................................................................................................................................................

This is my code.

```
<form name="setup" method="post" action="" ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkform(this);">
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox1" id="mycheckbox1" value="0"/> mycheckbox1.
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox2" id="mycheckbox2" value="0"/> mycheckbox2.
<br>
<input type="submit" name="back" value="Back"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next"/>
</form>


<?php
    if(isset($_POST["back"]))
    {
      echo $_POST[mycheckbox1];
      echo $_POST[mycheckbox2];
      echo "BACK";
    }
?>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
      echo $_POST[mycheckbox1];
      echo $_POST[mycheckbox2];
      echo "submit";
    }
?>


<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function checkform ( form )
{
  if ((form.mycheckbox1.checked == false ) && (form.mycheckbox2.checked == false )) 
  {
    alert( "Please select checkbox before press next button." );
    form.mycheckbox1.focus();
    return false ;
  }
return true ;
}
//-->
</script>
```

How can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Change you button type to "button", and call your function from there.

```
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Next" onClick="checkform('setup')"/>
```

Also, add your submit funcionality to your function, if it passes.
Add an ID to your form, so this works:

I want to use function checkform for next button onnly.

If user click BACK Button , not checkfrom, How can i do ?

This is my code.

mycheckbox1.
 mycheckbox2.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function checkform ( form )
{
  if ((form.mycheckbox1.checked == false ) && (form.mycheckbox2.checked == false )) 
  {
    alert( "Please select checkbox before press next button." );
    form.mycheckbox1.focus();
//Failed - do nothing
    //return false ;
  }else{
//passed, send the form
document.getElementById("setup").submit();

}
//return true ;
}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: where to place them `document.getElementById("setup").submit();`

Comment: I edited my post to show the whole function.  There is no need to return True or False.  You show an alert if it fails.  You submit the form if it passes.

Comment: not alert when click next . i think script unknow  mycheckbox1 and mycheckbox2 value.

Comment: This is true.  Add ID tags to them, and call the reference to them with the same sort of getElementById("id") method used for the submit.  You really don't even need to pass the form name into the function.

Comment: So in this line `if ((form.mycheckbox1.checked == false ) && (form.mycheckbox2.checked == false ))` , how to apply them ?

Comment: if (document.getElementById("mycheckbox1").checked==false).  Make sure you add an id="mycheckbox1" to your checkbox.

Comment: oh yeah, and your back button.  It should not a be a "submit".  It should be "button".  And add an onClick="window.history.back()" to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="button" name="back" value="Back"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next"/>
```

Comment: <vr> ====> <br> thanh

Comment: when i use your code, i can not use `if(isset($_POST["back"]))`